# How to represent len('') in a form different to the standard integer - Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, char, integer

I'm making a hangman game in python. I want to display the amount of characters in the word, but instead of it producing the integer as the amount of characters, I would like it instead to be '_'(one for every character.)

```
word = input('Please enter a word for your opponent:')
print(len(word) as '_') #Instead of an integer
```

Comment: That would be '_' * len(word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what Kenny Ostrom has suggested in the comment above, just answering it here so this question can be marked complete:

Strings in Python can be repeated n times by using the following syntax:

```
s = 'hello'
n = 3
p = s * n # p is equal to "hellohellohello"
```

So what you're looking for is:

```
print(len(word) * '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most simpliest form, this is probably what you're looking for.

```
print('_'*len('Foo'))
```

What's happening in this instance? Well breaking it down step by step looks like this

```
'_'*len('Foo')   
'_'*3
'___'
```

There's some steps here, but the core concept is that some operators work on strings

You should take some time out of your day and learn about some operators and comparsions that can be used with strings. Here's the offical Documentation for python 3

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

If that's too much of an eyesore, youtube is great too.

Answer (score 0):

It might look better as:

```
' '.join('_' * 5) # '_ _ _ _ _'
```